# How to create a table from different query results SQL

Tags: sql

I want to create a new table using the results from some  queries. I might be looking at this the wrong way so please feel free to let me know. Because of this I will try to make this question simple without putting my code to match each employee number with each manager level column from table2

I have two tables, one has employee names and employee numbers example

table 1

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| emplpyeenum | firstname |   last name |    location |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 11          |    joe    |    free     | JE          |
| 22          |   jill    |   yoyo      | XX          |
| 33          |    yoda   |   null      | 9U          |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

and another table with employee numbers under each manager level so basically a hierarchy example

Table 2

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| manager | manager2 | manager3 |
+---------+----------+----------+
|      11 |       22 |       33 |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I want to make a new table that will have the names besides the numbers, so for example but with employee number beside the names

```
+---------+--------+----------+
| level 1 | level2 |  level3  |
+---------+--------+----------+
| jill    |   joe  |    yoda  |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

How can I do this?

edit sorry guys I don't have permission to create a new table or view

Comment: Do you know how to write a query that gives you the values you want in the new table?

Comment: @Shawn no, I was just creating multiple  inner joins based on employee number from table 1 to the manager columns in table 2

Comment: Learn how to do `JOIN`.

Comment: @Eric sorry I know how to do a join. I am doing inner joins but don't knwo how to organize the new two to look the way I want which is show the hierarchy

Comment: What determine the hierarchy?

Comment: @Eric it's who reports to who. so it starts from the lowest to the highest

Comment: Why not change table two.. Make it have rows per manager instead of columns.. So two fields employeenum and managerlevel. If it can't be changed make a view by doing multiple selects with unions. You can then do one join, index it etc.. It will be in a better structure.

Comment: @JamesCooke I would like the table to have each column as manager level there name and employee number beside it how can I change the view to that?

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your `table2` to this?

```
+------------+----------+
| EmployeeId | ManagerId|
+------------+----------+
|      11    |     NULL |
+------------+----------+
|      22    |     11   |
+------------+----------+
|      33    |     22   |
+------------+----------+
```

Then you can do what you want with the data.  At least your data will be properly normalized.  In your `table2`.  What happen if employee 33 hire another employee below him?  You will add another column?

Based on your available table, this should give you the result you want.

```
SELECT m1.firstname, m2.firstname, m3.firstname
FROM table2 t
LEFT JOIN table1 m1 ON m1.employeenum = t.manager
LEFT JOIN table1 m2 ON m2.employeenum = t.manager2
LEFT JOIN table1 m3 ON m3.employeenum = t.manager3
```

Comment: no I need to show who reports to who so having each manager level coloumn works best here :(

Comment: @bleeetiso Storing data and displaying data are two completely different things.  If you store data in a messed up format.  Good luck trying to retrieve it.  Maybe you should read some introductory relational database books.

Comment: @bleeetiso https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: @bleeetiso https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: sorry I failed to mention I don't have permission to create a new table or view

Comment: @bleeetiso so if you can't create  a new table, why do you say this "I want to make a new table that will have the names besides the numbers ..."?

Comment: sorry I meant query two tables together to get that result. that what I meant by make. I choice of wording is bad

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a basic create table, then do a `insert select to` that will fill the table the way you need it. All you have to do is replace the select statement that I provided with the one you used to create the levels table output.

```
create table Levels
(
level1 varchar(25),
level2 varchar(25),
level3 varchar(25)
)


insert into Levels(level1, level2, level3)
select * from tables --here you would put the select statement that you used to create the information. If you dont have this script then let me know
```

Comment: thanks @B.Cratty my script is just select  emplpyeenum firstname  last name from  table1 inner join on table2 where table1.emplpyeenum = manager.  I made this query for each manager level column I don't knwo if there is an easier way so I don't have to make a new inner join query for each manager level

Comment: I don't have permission to  create a new table or view